# sklearn cross validation wildly different results from manual cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

The following code, which uses the function `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` and the scikit learn compatible `XGBClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

cv_clf = XGBClassifier(gpu_id=0, tree_method='gpu_hist', n_estimators=300, max_depth=9)
cv = sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate(estimator=cv_clf, X=X, y=labels, scoring='accuracy', verbose=100, n_jobs=4, cv=10)
```

produces results that are wildly different from the code below, even though they're pretty much supposed to do the same thing:

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

for train_indices, test_indices in sss.split(np.zeros(len(labels)), labels):
    X_train = dataset.data[train_indices]
    y_train = labels[train_indices]
    X_test = dataset.data[test_indices]
    y_test = labels[test_indices]
    age_train = age.values[train_indices]
    age_test = age.values[test_indices]
    X_train = np.concatenate([X_train, age_train], axis=1)
    X_test = np.concatenate([X_test, age_test], axis=1)
    cv_clf = XGBClassifier(gpu_id=0, tree_method='gpu_hist', n_estimators=300, n_jobs=4, max_depth=9)
    cv_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = cv_clf.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(preds, y_test)
    print(accuracy)
```

`X` in the first code listing is the same as `np.concatenate([dataset.data, age], axis=1)`

In the first case, the accuracy is very low (40-70), in the second case, it's 88-91.

Comment: Both code chunks do slightly different things, the “by hand” approach is not a standard cross-validation.

Comment: @Tim in what sense is it not standard?

Comment: @Tim Hmm I changed StratifiedShuffleSplit to StratifiedKFold in the manual approach and the accuracy dropped to similar values as those obtained from cross validate. But I'm a bit confused. How can the drop be so dramatic?

Comment: @Tim I'm especially confused because before running the above experiments I ran experiments with `GridSearch` with the `cv` parameter set to 10, and that gave me good accuracy

Comment: I meant to say `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Are your rows in a particular order? `StratifiedShuffleSplit` obviously randomizes the order, whereas `StratifiedKFold` does not by default. Also, what's the size of your dataset?

Comment: @BenReiniger indeed that was problem! The rows were arranged by experiment. Setting `shuffle=True` in `cross_validate` solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for `cross_validate`, parameter `cv` (as of v0.24.2):

> For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, `StratifiedKFold` is used. In all other cases, `Fold` [sic] is used. These splitters are instantiated with `shuffle=False` so the splits will be the same across calls.

The first sentence clarifies that your manual approach, with `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, is not the same as the cross-validation strategy of the first approach (k-fold).  However, you would still expect the scores to be closer than what you're seeing.

The real problem is from the second sentence.  Your `cross_validate` doesn't shuffle the data, while your manual approach does.  If your data comes in a particular order, this can dramatically affect scores.  You can fix this by passing an explicit cross-validation generator, e.g. `cross_validate(..., cv=sss)`.  Whether you *want* to shuffle the data depends on what the order of your rows means.